# Include KRPano in Webpack project

Tags: javascript, webpack, krpano

I'm using Webpack as core for all my front-end js project since more than a year. I'm starting to work with KRPano to create customized virtual tour. My goal is to be able to continue using my module style developement with Webpack, and include KRPano to this kind of project.

Actually the framework is a JS file with several functions to embed the viewer etc... And several js files that contains all krpano plugins.

I tried to just export the krpano file functions and include that in my project, but i got several errors and impossible de compile.

Wanted to know if someone ever done something like that, or if is there an alternative to webpack that will allow me to solve that issue ?

Thanks,
Navalex.

Answer (score 0):

There are many similar frameworks. And each for their own purposes. Frameworks like Electron, Cordova may suit you. On Cordova, I created APK from Krpano tour and worked fine on my phone

Answer (score 0):

Maybe your problem is that krpano is already "webpacked" and depending on which framework are you working you need the builded version and a server running.

What i have done is:

- create react app
- import vtour folder inisde src (for example)
- navigate with a single button into vtour/index.html
- build js app (react in my case)
- add vtour files in the same route in builded app
- sumbit to githubpages or glitch.me or something to test

Result Example:
https://imaciap.github.io/Manresa360Deploy/